# Pass elements of an array to instantiate a class

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, class

I'll start off by asking the particular question, and then include the link to the question I'm actually trying to apply this to at the end.

The immediate question is as follows:

Suppose I'm given an array of arrays, such as:

array = [[1, 10, 9] [2, 19, 4] [3, 7, 6]]

Where each individual array represents an employee, the first number is the employee's id, the second is their high score on some game, and the third number is their lowest score.

And I have a class called 'Employee' as follows:

`class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id, high_score, low_score):
        self.id = id
        self.high_score = high_score
        self.low_score = low_score`

Now, all I want to do is take that barebone array I was given, and for each sub-array, pass its inner values and create a new Employee object.

The goal here is to basically organize the data from the array I was given into some type of dictionary or new table where I can now refer to those elements like emp1.id, emp1.high_score, instead of having to index like array[0][0].

Cheers!

For those of you interested, I'm using this to solve the following problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/employee-importance/description/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try list unpacking

```
employee_array = [[1, 10, 9] [2, 19, 4] [3, 7, 6]]
employees = [Employee(*row) for row in employee_array]
```